# Design pattern suggestion work flow manager

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

I need to implement a work flow  manager sort of implementation.We have three module in our application which follow workflow strategy . Lets say i create an event then i send it to review , he may approve it or refer it back to me asking to do some modifications.In each case  i have to send email notification so can you please suggest me some sort of design pattern for this or should it be straight forward implementation.Three modules follow this .

Answer (score 0):

So, you basically need state management and events to trigger when state changes, you might think of looking into following:

Observer Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Also use database to store states as you mentioned you need to show them up to user.